# Concatenate lists in JINJA2

Tags: python, jinja2

How can I concatenate two list variables in jinja2?

E.G.

```
GRP1 = [1, 2, 3]
GRP2 = [4, 5, 6]

{# This works fine: #}
{% for M in GRP1 %}
    Value is {{M}}
{% endfor %}


{# But this does not: #}
{% for M in GRP1 + GRP2 %}
    Value is {{M}}
{% endfor %}
```

So, I have tried to concatenate the two lists using + (like you would in Python), but it turns out that they are not lists, but python `xrange` objects:

```
jijna2 error: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'xrange' and 'xrange'
```

Is there a way for me to iterate over the concatenation of GRP1 and GRP2 in the same for loop?

Comment: Concatenating via `GRP1 + GRP2` is available now. My jinja2 version is `v.2.9.5`

Answer (score 25, accepted):

AFAIK you can't do it using native Jinja2 templating. You're better off creating a new combined iterable and passing that to your template, eg:

```
from itertools import chain

x = xrange(3)
y = xrange(3, 7)
z = chain(x, y) # pass this to your template
for i in z:
    print i
```

As per comments, you can explicitly convert the iterables into lists, and concatenate those:

```
{% for M in GRP1|list + GRP2|list %}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The problem is that I am not using it directly in Python - I am using it in an application that reads in a text file and does the Jinja processing behind the scenes, i.e. I can't actually modify the Python code.

Comment: @KernowBunney In that case, either 2 loops - or see if `{% for M in GRP1|list + GRP2|list %}` works...

Comment: This was very useful in Ansible, while building routes for a AWS VPC.  I made each route as an individual array fact and then joined them all into one array with `vpc_routes: "{{ vpc_main_routes + optional_route1|default([]) + optional_route2|default([]) }}"`.  Note either of the optional routes could be undefined.

Comment: {% for M in GRP1|list + GRP2|list %} works but how to get unique values?

Comment: Probably easiest to put something that's the result of `set().union(var1, var2)` in the template context and use that @user2125117

Answer (score 18):

Concatenating lists like `{{ GRP1 + GRP2 }}` is available, in jinja2 versions 2.9.5 and above.

@Hsiao gave this answer originally as a comment